# Wave particle duality and gravity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse

Is a particle's center of gravity at the center of its wave function or is it where we would measure the particle to be? When we measure a particle does its center of gravity shift to where the particle is measured?

Answer (score 5):

The wave function only predicts the probability distribution of finding a particle or a system of particles at an (x,y,z). The center of a wavefunction  $Ψ$ is not a well defined concept, as it is different for different boundary conditions. It obeys the symmetries imposed by the interactions that define the $Ψ$ .

In any case at present the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) has elementary particles defined  as point particles,i.e. no dimensions, and the center of mass/gravity of course is at that point, and is the point whose measurement will verify the probability distribution,  $Ψ*Ψ$, when enough events/measurements with the same boundary conditions are accumulated.

Such elementary paticles are described by plane wave wavefunctions which are spread all over the place. A free electron has to be represented by a [wavepacket wave function](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html) ,

[image: wavepacket]

but as the center of gravity/mass is where the electron is, the wave function squared will give the *probability* of finding it away from the maximum probability, which is the center for this wavepacket.

Complex systems, as [the proton](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/) and the neutron, will have an extension in space, and the instantaneous center of mass would be part of the model calculating the quantity of interest to measure. The [models for hadrons](https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/10760/1/NDA.pdf) are complicated .

In general, in quantum mechanical problems, it is the symmetries of the interaction that are embedded in the wavefunction, [the wave function](https://web.phys.ksu.edu/vqm/tutorials/interpretingwavefunctions/exploring.html) itself may be all over a large space, depending on the problem under study, and its center has no usable meaning with respect to the center of mass of the particle-system  modeled.

Comment: Surely though one could extend the concept of center of mass to  a superposition of states instead of position vector. It would be probabilistic, but I don’t immediate see an issue with just replacing the position vectors with the states in Hilbert space  and then projecting onto position space.

Comment: @InertialObserver    supeposition of states would be probability distribution also., see the wave packet above.

Comment: I see, for some reason I didn’t see the figure at the first pass for some reason.

Comment: @InertialObserver  I put it in after your comment !!